# Interesting combinatorics competition question

Tags: combinatorics

I have 120 blocks. Each block is one of 2 different materials, 3 different colors, 4 different sizes and 5 different shapes. No two blocks have exactly the same all four properties. I take two blocks at random. What is the probability that these two blocks have exactly two of these four properties the same?

my way of solving it was to bash it out basically. First i would set 2 of the characteristic constant and then choose 2 of the other ones then add up all the combinations.

${2}\choose{1}$ ${3}\choose{1}$ ${4}\choose{2}$ ${5}\choose{2}$ ...divided by ${120}\choose{2}$

in the end I got the answer 35/238 but I would like to get it checked as I don't have the solution manual.

Comment: Your answer is off by a factor of $2$, because choosing the properties doesn't choose the blocks. A term like $\binom 21 \binom 31 \binom 42 \binom 52$ correctly counts things like "wooden, red, big+small, round+square", but there are $2$ pairs of blocks with those properties: either "big red wooden square block + small red wooden round block", or "big red wooden round block + small red wooden square block".

Comment: @MishaLavrov oh I see thank you for spotting my mistake. And just to clarify I over counted by 2 because there are 2 different ways to pick the blocks? like a and b or b and a right?

Comment: No; the order of the blocks should not matter, because it does not matter in the denominator. There are two ways to put together the properties: like abcd and abef, or abcf and abed.

Comment: You can also cancel $7$ in the numerator and denominator: $35/119=5/17$.